# Which prototype properties shared between instances

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/F5ZSA/1/

Here's the code from above fiddle:

```
"use strict";

function Human()
{
    this.myname;
    this.things = [];
    this.addThing = function(string)
    {
        this.things.push(string);
    }

    this.getThings = function()
    {
        return this.things;
    }

    this.setName = function(name)
    {
        this.myname = name;   
    }

    this.getName = function()
    {
        return this.myname;   
    }
}

Mister.prototype = new Human();
function Mister()
{

}

var mister1 = new Mister();
var mister2 = new Mister();

mister1.setName("Peter");
mister2.setName("Steven");

mister1.addThing("mister1 reporting");
mister2.addThing("mister 2 reporting");

console.log(mister1.getName());
console.log(mister2.getName());
console.log(mister1.getThings());
console.log(mister2.getThings());
```

When you run it, the result suggests that 'myname' property is different for each Mister instance, while 'things' property seems to be shared between all instances. Is it suppose to be like that? If yes, what is the general rule telling which prototype properties are shared among 'inheriting' objects?

Coming from other OOP languages, my intuition was that every object should have a separate prototype instance. Is it a good idea to try to enforce it in js?

Comment: this is because misterX prototype is the same object. the keyword 'this' in Human is the mister context not human context. but in case of Array it refers to the same thing in the memory.

Comment: Yes, but why in case of 'myname' it's not the same thing in memory for both Mister1 and Mister2? What makes Array different?

Comment: new Human() is the same thing as Object.create(Human.prototype). What is does is it creates the new object by cloning whatever is in the prototype. in javascript the primitive variables are copied by value and objects (Array) is copied by reference. so that is why your name is different but pointer to the array the same.

Comment: and lookup the this keyword in javascript. it behaves different way to traditional OOP languages. in this case it 'this' in mister1 points to mister one and 'this' in mister2 points to mister2, but this.things points to array reference in javascript even though mister1.things and mister2.things are not the same things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic problem when coming from traditional OOP languages. By creating the new object the prototype is copied. The keyword 'this' already refers to new object, but the reference to another object from the prototype as yours this.things refers still to the same space in the memory. When you create two objects you create two references to the same object (in this case array)

the following will work as you would expect. To go around the 'this' issue i put there the init method called to initialise the object, in this case to create multiple array objects, each for new object Mister.

```
var Human = function()
{

    this.myname;
    this.things;
    this.things;

    return {
      addThing:function(string)
      {
          this.things.push(string);
      },

      getThings:function()
      {
          return this.things;
      },

      setName: function(name)
      {
          this.myname = name;
      },

      getName: function()
      {
          return this.myname;
      },
      init: function(){
              this.things = new Array();
            }
    }

}


var Mister = function(){}
Mister.prototype = new Human();

var mister1 = new Mister();
var mister2 = Object.create(Mister.prototype);
mister1.init();
mister2.init();


mister1.setName("Peter");
mister2.setName("Steven");

mister1.addThing("mister1 reporting");
mister2.addThing("mister 2 reporting");

console.log(mister1.getName());
console.log(mister2.getName());
console.log(mister1.getThings());
console.log(mister2.getThings());
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. I've re-wrote this to mimic traditional OOP a little bit more: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg7w9/

I wonder if it's good practice to  use this kind of mechanism in JS. In my current project I wanted to use a pub/sub pattern, so I've created an 'EventDispatcher' 'class' to inherit from. Now, I assumed every inheriting object should have a separate subscribers list, but it is possible to keep one list for all objects. Which way is more proper in JS world?